# Error: Failed with error: No such Project : polymod

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

I am trying to make a Friday Night Funkin' mod, but when I compile it, this error shows up:

```
Error: Could not find haxelib "polymod", does it need to be installed?
```

So of course I tried to install it, but then this showed up:

```
Error: Failed with error: No such Project : polymod
```

Btw I used this command to (at least try) to install polymod:

```
haxelib install polymod
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of a few weeks ago, [Polymod is now available on HaxeLib](https://lib.haxe.org/p/polymod).

The following command (which previously did not work) is now the CORRECT way to install Polymod:

```
haxelib install polymod
```

Answer (score 1):

The library is not published to lib.haxe.org, which is why `haxelib install` doesn't work. According to the [official build instructions](https://github.com/ninjamuffin99/Funkin#build-instructions), the correct command is:

```
haxelib git polymod https://github.com/larsiusprime/polymod.git
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with polymod but now it tells me to install discord_rpc, and it shows the same error

Comment: Maybe use the build instructions I linked? ;)

Comment: Well, I can't find it's repository on github.

Comment: What do you mean? It's listed in the build instructions.

Comment: Your instructions didn't work but I found a way out and now it's solved! Thanks!

Comment: Polymod is on HaxeLib now so this answer is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're using Lix it's be :)

```
lix install gh:larsiusprime/polymod
```