# I keep getting an error for polymod even though I have polymod installed

Tags: powershell

The error reads

> source/TitleState.hx:54: characters 3-18 : Type not found : polymod.Polymod
> source/Note.hx:10: characters 8-33 : Type not found : polymod.format.ParseRules

But I already have polymod installed...

Comment: @marc_s why did you use a quote and not a code block?

Comment: That's the generally accepted standard way of formatting error messages

Comment: @marc_s okay, didn’t know that. Thank you

Comment: @erwdfsfsef Welcome to SO.  [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229067/11609403).  Not quite sure why this is tagged as `powershell`, when I suspect `haxe` and `haxlib` would suffice.